# Unable to use fetch on iOS Simulator (Trying to access https://{domainName}.amazonaws.com:8080/{uri} ) (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, fetch, react-native-ios

I am building a mobile application in React Native which consumes my service (SSL Enabled) deployed to AWS.
I'm unable to perform fetch on the AWS EC2 domain from the iOS Simulator. I can access the URL through Postman and simulator's browser.
When I use fetch from the iOS Simulator, I'm getting a

```
TypeError: Network Request Failed
```

I have added the following to my info.plist.

```
<key>{domainName}.amazonaws.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
```